# Copy only OS which isn't partitioned to SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, windows-8.1

I am using Paragon Hard Disk Managment to move Windows 8.1 from HDD to SSD. The SSD is smaller (120gb) and the HDD is bigger. Both is installed and running on computer.

The problem is that windows and all files are in the same partition so I don't know which files I should move and which ones to leave. And I can't move everything as the SSD is too small. To make stuff clear. All data are in the same partition on the HDD.

So the question is. Of the following checkboxes. Which of them should be checked to move OS safely?

*Extra-mini-question: Is it a good idea to backup files before copy?*

[image: Paragon migration]

Comment: If the amount of used space isn't larger than the SSD you can migrate everything.

Comment: The data on the HDD is three times as much as the SSD can hold. Sorry for not writing that

Comment: I think that you're asking this question is that you know what you have to do, but recheck Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are the essential selections you have to make for a typical system:
[image: Windows System]

You can always try again.

Comment: Thanks. But Do I really have to move All program files and users? I hav eno place for all programs all all user files on the SSD. Well maybe programfiles but certainly not Users.
Everything not yellow could be unchecked?